# How to get a matching string by comparing 2 strings?

Tags: php, string

I was once asked a question in an interview that if we have 2 strings, how we can get a part of matching string from these two?
for example

```
$str1 = "My name is baig";
$str2 = "Baig is a nice person";
```

now i want the output 
**"i a e s g"** and other matching letters

I want this in Php

Thanks in advance

Comment: only a first advise: explode lowered strings by space, like `explode(' ', mb_strtolower($strX))` and then do an `array_intersect($arr_strX, $arr_strY)`

Comment: str_word_count() is better than explode() for ASCII text because it can handle punctuation

Comment: There's no mention of matching words in the question, nor case sensitivity rules, nor word occurrence intersections ... bad question =/

Answer (score 1):

this is code to get the expected result for two string str1 and str2

```
<?php
  $str1 = strtolower("My name is baig");
  $str2 = strtolower("Baig is a nice person");
  $array1 = explode(' ',$str1);
  $array2 = explode(' ',$str2);
  $result = array_intersect($array2, $array1);

  print_r(implode(' ',$result));
?>
```

Comment: Fails because of case sensitive `array_insersect`

Comment: @rabudde corrected this slight mistake. Just edit the answer for this kind of detail :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you have several options... 
If you want matches in a specific order, meaning is a string inside another string, you might go for strstr, if you want to find any common point between 2 strings, you might want to first find an explode pattern, in your case a space.

Expode both string and intersect both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_intersect` after use the function `explode` on your string.
A working example :
http://codepad.org/IikNr2Vv 
But this is case sensitive, `Baig` will be different of `baig`.
 To resolve this, you can use the `strtolower` function to transform to lower cas all your string.

Answer (score 0):

got the following answer from another forum

```
<?php 
$str1   = "My name is baig";
$str2   = "Baig is a nice person";
$r1     = str_split(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-z]/","",strtolower($str1)));
$r2     = str_split(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-z]/","",strtolower($str2))); 
$match  = array_unique(array_intersect($r1,$r2)); 

$match = implode(" ",$match); 
echo "Matched letters are: ".$match; 
?>
```

Case sensitivity is still an issue but i will go through it